# TCL: linking with static library in windows

Tags: c, compilation, tcl, static-libraries

I have downloaded TCL source from [here](https://www.tcl.tk/software/tcltk/download.html) and I can compile it to generate static library in Windows7 using the following command

```
nmake -f makefile.vc OPTS=static INSTALLDIR=path_to_your_install_dir
nmake -f makefile.vc install OPTS=static INSTALLDIR=path_to_your_install_dir
```

In the output, I can get `tcl87s.lib - tcldds14s.lib - tclreg13s.lib`

Now I am trying to build my C code (that has TCL embedded):

```
static const char *user_script = "puts \"Hello World ........\"\n";

int my_cmd(Tcl_Interp *interp, const char *arg_str, ...){
  char *cmd_str = Tcl_Alloc(256);
  va_list ap;
  int result;
  va_start(ap,arg_str);
  vsprintf(cmd_str, arg_str, ap);
  result = Tcl_Eval(interp,cmd_str);
  Tcl_Free(cmd_str);
  return result;
}

int main (int argc ,char *argv[])
{
    Tcl_FindExecutable(argv[0]);
    Tcl_Interp *myinterp;
    printf ("C: Starting ... \n");
    myinterp = Tcl_CreateInterp();

    if (Tcl_Init(myinterp) != TCL_OK) {
        printf("Error: %s\n",Tcl_GetStringResult(myinterp));
        return TCL_ERROR;
    }

    if (my_cmd(myinterp, user_script) != TCL_OK) {
        printf("Error: %s\n",Tcl_GetStringResult(myinterp));
        return TCL_ERROR;
    }
    
    Tcl_DeleteInterp(myinterp);
    Tcl_Finalize();
    return TCL_OK;
}
```

Because I need to build it in Windows, I am compiling this code in Visual Studio Command Prompt:

```
cl -I"D:\path\to\tcl\include" myCode.c D:\path\to\tcl87s.lib
```

But unfortunately, I get always these errors:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__Tcl_Alloc referenced in function ...
error ....................................__imp__Tcl_Free ..................
error ....................................__imp__Tcl_CreateInterp ..................
```

.........and more errors for other TCL functions.......

If I built TCL as a dymanic library, no errors and I can compile my C code. Does anyone know what could be the problem

Comment: Alas, you need advice from someone who builds on Windows. That's a platform I don't use for development; I don't have a toolchain for it (much less the same one you have) and I have little experience with the way projects work there. _However,_ that message seems to be a sign that functions are not getting bound to their implementations, and indicates a missing library. The way binding of the Tcl library works definitely varies according to link option; in a static link, it should be directly to the named functions, not to their import stubs.

Comment: @DonalFellows .. thanks for your response .. It turned out that I have to use flag -DSTATIC_BUILD while compiling my C code.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that I have to use flag -DSTATIC_BUILD while compiling my C code.